# building brackets was "Done, without errors" in Debian Wheezy, but

Tags: gruntjs, chromium-embedded, adobe-brackets, brackets-shell

i was trying to build "brackets sprint 40" from source code (by following @jasonsanjose instructions look [#4816](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/4816) and the official wiki's page [here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/wiki/Building-Brackets-Shell#linux)) in my 32bit Wheezy, Using CEF3 (Verion  **3.1547.1406_linux32_release** with **glibc 2.13**) and everything was OK .
when i ran **grunt build** and **grunt installer** the output was:

```
    Running "build" task
    Running "build-linux" task
    Done, without errors.
```

and when i installed .deb package and executed it in the terminal , this error has been thrown:

```
brackets: libcef_dll/wrapper/libcef_dll_wrapper.cc:120: int CefExecuteProcess(const CefMainArgs&, CefRefPtr): Assertion `false' failed.
Aborted
```

I did rebuild it many times, but the problem persist.
And this is where i stopped, i don't know where the problem lies.
some help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a duplicate of this question with longer discussion posted here - https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/8170.

Note: This problem shouldn't affect a "vanilla" brackets-shell build on Linux -- it's specific to a hack some people have developed to [support an older version of Debian](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/4816) than Brackets officially supports. This requires swapping in a newer version of the [CEF](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) library, which is not always easy to do since they are not usually backwards-compatible.